# The GET method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: POST. laravel-8

Tags: php, laravel, forms, request, laravel-8

I created routes with type (POST), and when visit it directly, it get this error:

**The GET method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: POST.**

how to handle getting this error if anyone visit it from URL without press a form submit or something like that.

the routes:

```
Route::group(['middleware'=>'guest:web'], function(){
Route::post('/post-login', [LoginController::class,'postLogin'])->name('site.postLogin');
Route::post('/register-create', [registerController::class,'create'])->name('site.register.create');
});
```

if anyone visited these routes (type POST) directly, it will redirect him to the above error

how to handle the POST routes in laravel in this case?

Comment: I made them POST cuz these routes will save data from user, but the issue is, if anyone take these URLs (type POST), and hit it in the browser it will redirect him to this error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to have routes available via GET *and* POST you can use `match()`:

```
Route::group(['middleware'=>'guest:web'], function(){
   Route::match(['get', 'post'], '/post-login', [LoginController::class,'postLogin'])->name('site.postLogin');
   Route::match(['get', 'post'], '/register-create', [registerController::class,'create'])->name('site.register.create');
});
```

More on [Available Router Methods](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/routing#available-router-methods)